# i want to make counter time in Android

Tags: java, android

I create a Android app and I want to make time counter. there are two long variables that it storage long data.

When running second finished, walking second must started and after this process go on four times that must finished.

```
 public void Counter(long runsecond, final long walksecond) {
    new CountDownTimer(runsecond, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            showtext.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            showtext.setText("done!");
            new CountDownTimer(walksecond, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    showtext.setText("done!");
                }
            }.start();


        }
    }.start();
}
```

i take in for. only it count once. how can i correct this problem?

Comment: Its not clear what you want to achieve. You want to repeat whole running/walking cycle two times? In simple words `run for X sec -> walk for Y sec -> run for X sec -> walk for Y sec`?

Comment: yes like you said. how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that might satisfy your needs. Number of seconds for both, run and walk counters, is configurable. Repeat rate specifies, how many times should both counters run.

```
public enum CounterType {
    RUN_COUNTER,
    WALK_COUNTER
}

private void start() {
    int runSeconds = 5;
    int walkSeconds = 5;
    int repeatRate = 4; // 2 - run, 2 walk

    startCount(runSeconds, walkSeconds, repeatRate, RUN_COUNTER);
}

private void startCount(final int runSeconds, final int walkSeconds, final int repeatRate, final CounterType actualCounter) {
    if (repeatRate == 0) {
        return;
    }

    int actualSeconds = 0;
    if (actualCounter == RUN_COUNTER) {
        actualSeconds = runSeconds;
    } else if (actualCounter == WALK_COUNTER) {
        actualSeconds = walkSeconds;
    }

    new CountDownTimer(actualSeconds * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("Counter - onTick", actualCounter.toString() + ": millis remaining: " + millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("Counter - onFinish", actualCounter.toString());
            CounterType nextCounter = actualCounter == RUN_COUNTER ? WALK_COUNTER : RUN_COUNTER;
            startCount(runSeconds, walkSeconds, repeatRate - 1, nextCounter);
        }
    }.start();
}
```